# Scale Meteor App to Mobile Screen Size

Tags: meteor

I've started playing around with meteor to see if I can utilize it for mobile app development.  I'm currently running into an issue where the mobile version of the site looks exactly like the desktop (except with the small screen, you cant read the text on the mobile).

If I resize the desktop, it looks how I would anticipate the app to look however it doesn't look right when I connect on my iPhone.

Here are the images of the screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGsyc.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting this in the `<head>` section of your app:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will scale the window to the device.